# Error during sbt execution: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sbt/State$Next

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I am trying to run sbt package to build my scala project but after downloading the jars from repository its throwing me following error-

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sbt/State$Next
>           at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:28)
>           at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
>           at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
>           at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
>           at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
>           at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
>           at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
>           at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
>           at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
>           at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sbt.State$Next
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>           ... 10 more Error during sbt execution: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sbt/State$Next

My sbt file looks like-

```
name := "Simple Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.0"
```

Please let me know how to resolve the issue, I am new to scala and sbt concept. Thanks

Comment: Can you post your build files?

Comment: FWIW this happened to me when running from IntelliJ and killing and restarting after deleting `~/.sbt` had me back up and running.